# XSLT for-each-group with for-each : help to understand behaviour needed

Tags: xslt

I'm an XSLT novice.

We have the below XML transformation produced via XSLT.

The output lineitem-position comes out as a single value for each group element.
But the output line_amount comes out as a list of values for each group element.

Why is the output line_amount coming out as a list of values please.

Details below.

input:

```xml
<order order-no="60058554">
    <product-lineitems>
        <product-lineitem>
            <gross-price>76.00</gross-price>
            <position>1</position>
            <quantity unit="">2.0</quantity>
            <custom-attributes>
                <custom-attribute attribute-id="associatedPromotionId">Reward1Band2</custom-attribute>
                <custom-attribute attribute-id="associatedPromotionId">Reward2Band3</custom-attribute>
            </custom-attributes>
            <price-adjustments>
                <price-adjustment>
                    <gross-price>-38.00</gross-price>
                    <promotion-id>Reward1Band2</promotion-id>
                </price-adjustment>
                <price-adjustment>
                    <gross-price>-38.00</gross-price>
                    <promotion-id>Reward2Band3</promotion-id>
                </price-adjustment>
            </price-adjustments>
        </product-lineitem>
        <product-lineitem>
            <gross-price>50.00</gross-price>
            <position>2</position>
            <quantity unit="">2.0</quantity>
            <custom-attributes>
                <custom-attribute attribute-id="associatedPromotionId">Reward3Band3</custom-attribute>
            </custom-attributes>
            <price-adjustments>
                <price-adjustment>
                    <gross-price>-50.00</gross-price>
                    <promotion-id>Reward3Band3</promotion-id>
                </price-adjustment>
            </price-adjustments>
        </product-lineitem>
        <product-lineitem>
            <gross-price>28.00</gross-price>
            <position>3</position>
            <quantity unit="">1.0</quantity>
            <custom-attributes>
                <custom-attribute attribute-id="associatedPromotionId">Reward2Band3</custom-attribute>
            </custom-attributes>
            <price-adjustments>
                <price-adjustment>
                    <gross-price>-28.00</gross-price>
                    <promotion-id>Reward2Band3</promotion-id>
                </price-adjustment>
            </price-adjustments>
        </product-lineitem>
    </product-lineitems>
```

xslt:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xsi xsl ns1 soap wsdl xsd dw">
    
        <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
        
        <xsl:template match="/dw:order">
            <xsl:variable name="associatedPromotions">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="dw:product-lineitems/dw:product-lineitem" group-by="dw:custom-attributes/dw:custom-attribute[@attribute-id='associatedPromotionId']">
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <line>
                            <xsl:attribute name="lineitem-position">
                                <xsl:value-of select="dw:position"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="line_amount">
                                <xsl:value-of select="dw:gross-price"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </line>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:variable>`
        
        etc etc
   
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output snippet:

```
<lineitem-position>1</lineitem-position>
<line_amount>76.00 76.00 28.00 50.00</line_amount>
    
<lineitem-position>1</lineitem-position>
<line_amount>76.00 76.00 28.00 50.00</line_amount>

<lineitem-position>3</lineitem-position>
<line_amount>76.00 76.00 28.00 50.00</line_amount>

<lineitem-position>2</lineitem-position>
<line_amount>76.00 76.00 28.00 50.00</line_amount>
```

I was expecting the line_amount to come out as a single value, similar to line_position

Comment: Please provide a way to reproduce the problem - see: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I took your transformation, removed the `dw:` namespace to make it runnable (saxon kept complaining about the undefined namespace). I alsor removed the variable declaration since it did not have any way to output. And it worked. I don't see why your code should not work.
(Also, you forgot the closing `</order>` tag in your XML input)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xsi xsl ns1 soap wsdl xsd">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/order">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="product-lineitems/product-lineitem" group-by="custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id='associatedPromotionId']">
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <line>
                        <xsl:attribute name="lineitem-position">
                            <xsl:value-of select="position"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="line_amount">
                            <xsl:value-of select="gross-price"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </line>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<line lineitem-position="1" line_amount="76.00"/>
<line lineitem-position="1" line_amount="76.00"/>
<line lineitem-position="3" line_amount="28.00"/>
<line lineitem-position="2" line_amount="50.00"/>
```

Comment: Perhaps the namespace was actually the problem. Since the stylesheet that produced the wrong results was clearly different from the one we have been shown, it could have been anything.

Comment: thanks guys for your comments.
I've found the behaviour I was getting was caused by an extra intermediate for-each loop elsewhere in the xslt code.
I appreciate your feedback, which has helped me on my learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the behaviour I was getting was caused by an extra intermediate for-each loop elsewhere in the xslt code.
Thanks guys for your help, appreciated.

Comment: Please delete your question. This is not helping anyone.

Comment: Nick - if you can show your modification in the answer, readers in the future may find that helpful.